# Write NSDictionary to NSPasteboard

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsdictionary, nspasteboard

I have a dictionary containing an image in `NSData` format, the size of the image along with other attributes of image. How can i write an `NSDictionary` to `NSPasteboard`?

I wrote the code as following:

```
NSPasteboard *pasteBoard = [NSPasteboard generalPasteboard];
[pasteBoard clearContents];
[pasteBoard writeObjects:[NSArray arrayWithObject:myDictionary];
```

After compiling, It throws the following message in the console:

Instances of `class __NSDictionaryM` not valid for `NSPasteboard -writeObjects:`.  The `class __NSDictionaryM` does not implement the `NSPasteboardWriting` protocol.

Answer (score 2):

The objects should implement the protocol `NSPasteboardWriting` to be saved in the pasteBoard server.

The Cocoa framework classes `NSString`, `NSAttributedString`, `NSURL`, `NSColor`, `NSSound`, `NSImage`, and `NSPasteboardItem` implement this protocol. You can make your custom class conform to this protocol so that you can write instances of the class to a pasteboard using the writeObjects: method of NSPasteboard.

why not doing like this :

```
NSImage *image = ...;
NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObject:image];
NSPasteboard *pasteBoard = [NSPasteboard generalPasteboard];
[pasteBoard writeObjects:array];
```

Answer (score 0):

Either make your own class with this data and implement `NSPasteboardWriting` (and probably `NSPasteboardReading` too since you'll want to read this data out from your custom pasteboard format as well, since no other application will understand it), or use `setPropertyList:forType:` and `propertyList:forType:`.

Comment: I feel as you said i can use plist's. Can i write plist's to NSPasteboard?

Comment: "Property list" means a property list type. The property list types are array, dictionary, date, number, string and data. You may be able to use this if only property list types are involved. Since you are using a dictionary with a data value (which is okay), it depends on how you are storing the size. If you are using an NSValue with a size, you'll need to use either two NSNumbers or an NSString (using `NSSizeFromString` and `NSStringFromSize`).